# Unable to produce graphviz in RStudio presentation

Tags: r, rstudio, diagrammer, rpres

I am trying to create a slide deck that is a condensed version of a more thorough RMarkdown analysis.  My graphviz plots do not render in the RStudio presentation.

The graphviz plots properly render in my RMarkdown analysis.

The following code works in RMarkdown, but not RPresentation.

```r
DiagrammeR::grViz("
digraph rmarkdown {
A -> B
}
", height = 200)
```

I would have expected this diagram to render in my slide deck.  Instead I get an error:

```
Error in file(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection
```

Comment: DiagrammeR typically outputs html iirc and Rpres files don't play nice with html. I've quite a bit of luck with html using xaringan presentations: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xaringan/index.html

Comment: Thank you @tomasu.  I will give this a try later today.